# Error Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed al obtener el resultado de dos tablas Mysql diferentes en Java

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, jdbc

Este es mi primer ejercicio, en el que se me pide unir 2 tablas llamadas user y  enterprise, para que saque los nombres y apellidos de los usuarios y el nombre de su empresa, he aprendido un poco como funciona SQL en java de forma un tanto autodidacta y no se lo que pueda estar haciendo mal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //se crea la conexion
            Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruebas", "root","");

            //crear objeto statement
            Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement();

            //ejecutamos SQL
            ResultSet empresa = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM enterprise");
            ResultSet user = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");

            //recorrer  el resultSet
            while(empresa.next() && user.next()) {
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+user.getString("name") +", Apellido: "+user.getString("lastname")+", Nombre empresa: "+empresa.getString("name"));
            }

            //cerramos la conexion
            empresa.close();
            user.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no se puede conectar, el error es el siguiente:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Si solo uso una tabla y quiero ver su resultado funciona correctamente, si uso 2 ahí es cuando viene el siguiente fallo:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:733)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6279)
>         at Act2.Main.main(Main.java:23)

No entiendo muy bien que estoy haciendo mal, tal vez en vez de dos resultset deba usar mas SQL? por ejemplo hacer algo así?

```
select u.name, u.lastname, e.name
from enterprise as e, user as u
```

Alguien que me pueda explicar un poco ?

Comment: El error es básicamente porque estás usando la misma instancia de Statement para ambas querys, debería tener separadas los Statement,  seguro su error desaparece.

Comment: Nose si te he entendido correctamente pero acabo de probarlo he creado otro statement y me sigue dando error? podrías ponerme un ejemplo porfavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es básicamente porque estás usando la misma instancia de `Statement` para ambas querys, debería tener separadas los Statement, seguro su error desaparece [Documentación Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

```
Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement();
Statement miStatement2 = conexion.createStatement();

//ejecutamos SQL
ResultSet empresa = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM enterprise");
ResultSet user = miStatement2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");
```

Comment: ahora si entiendo muchísimas gracias!! no me di cuenta y había otro error que nada tenia que ver, pero me ha sido de muchísima utilidad verlo y saber que estaba colocan dolo correctamente y mi fallo era otro